# Hiding Magento Category Images On Page 2

Tags: magento-1.9, category, image, magento-community

How do you go about hiding category images on page 2 & beyond? In other words, just have the image load on page 1 & if there's more than 1 page of products...have the image hidden.

Comment: You want to show category image only for first page right??

Comment: Correct. If there's more than one page of products under the category/sub-category, I want the image to be hidden.

Comment: To be clear: the image should be hidden only on page 2, page 3, page 4, etc (not page 1)